Recreational Park fill of human android to full fill fantasies
Yesterday I watched Vice I tought was a remake of Miami Vice but I was so wrong, but the plot reminded me about a very nice movie I watched 20+ years ago.
They have a futuristic recreational park like Disneyland / Jurasic Park / Fantasy Island. Where rich people go to fullfill their fantasies. But they use androids to interact with users and create the ambience.
They have different scenarios, the most important was the Wild West where android reenacted some shotout and later are sent to workshop for repairs. But also remember one old roman / greek area with beautiful android girls feeding your grapes and stuff
Then they lost control of the android and they start chasing the main characters.
The main villian was a caucasian android cowboy with black outfit very fit and hairless head. From the Wild West scenario, and the one with a gun shooting people.

 Maybe I'm mixing movies. But I think at the end when everything is solved and they are going to escape in the park train there is a close up on some android  like they are still there or one additional chase and they finally shoot to the villian. 


You're describing Westworld, but it's not from the 90s.

@Walt You are right, but I say 20+ years for a rough stimated :P The edit added the 1990s. Thanks :)

Ah, that makes sense. I thought you said it was from those years, sorry. (It's about to be a series on HBO, BTW)

I believe you are thinking of the movie Westworld with Yul Brynner



I saw this on television one day as well and hadn't thought about it until your description. Yul Brynner plays a wild west android gone wrong who starts killing the tourists. 

Yul Brynner acting here was superb. Thanks

By the way, Westworld was written by Michael Crichton, who went on to write (the novel) Jurassic Park, which, as the OP points out, has some similar themes.
